# Reading 2 OR multiple excel worksheet in same perl program

Tags: perl, worksheet

I am trying to read 2 excel sheet in single perl program.

like this -->

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use IO::File;
use IO::Seekable;
use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel;

my $parser = Spreadsheet::ParseExcel->new();
my $workbook = $parser->Parse('FILE1.xls');
my $worksheet1 = $workbook->worksheet('Worksheet_name1');

my $workbookB  = $parser->Parse('FILE2.xls');
my $worksheetB = $workbookB->worksheet('Worksheet_name2');
```

But, I am facing this Error - 
Can't call method "worksheet" on an undefined value at ./PERL_PROGRAM.pl

Can someone give me some pointers.. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

The `parse` method returns `undef` if it fails, and you aren't checking for that.  (Which is why you get `Can't call method "worksheet" on an undefined value`.)  Also, it's `parse`, not `Parse` (Perl is case sensitive).  Try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel;

my $parser = Spreadsheet::ParseExcel->new();
my $workbook = $parser->parse('FILE1.xls') or die $parser->error;
my $worksheet1 = $workbook->worksheet('Worksheet_name1')
                 or die "Worksheet_name1 doesn't exist";

my $workbookB  = $parser->parse('FILE2.xls') or die $parser->error;
my $worksheetB = $workbookB->worksheet('Worksheet_name2')
                 or die "Worksheet_name2 doesn't exist";
```